# javascript not functioning when "examplelink.php#anchor" is clicked

Tags: javascript, scroll, anchor, smoothing

I **really, really** hope someone will help me with this! Thank you sooo much if you do! :)

I have two pages... one named **index.php** and one named **portfolio.php**.
My header (same on every page) contains some anchors rederecting them to the **portfolio.php** page (**portfolio.php#blogg**).

I also have a javascript code for **smooth scrolling** (this should work on all pages), but it does not work on the header anchor links when I'm in another page then **portfolio.php**.

What can I do to get the **javascript** to function when I for example press "**portfolio.php#blogg**" in the **index.php** page?

Heres my javascript:

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() { new SmoothScroll({ duration: 800 }); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm....   The problem, if I understand correctly, is that the browser jumps down to the fragment anchor position when arriving from another page, before the SmoothScroll object is loaded.  The first thing that comes to mind would be a solution that uses sessions or cookies.

When a user is on the index page and clicks on a link to portfolio that should scroll to the `#blogg` anchor:  Instead of adding the hashtag fragment to the URL of the link, save a cookie that indicates the page should be scrolled and link directly to the top of the portfolio page.

Then, in the portfolio page `domready` event, load the SmoothScroll object, check for the presence of the cookie, scroll to the `#blogg` anchor if it exists, and remove the cookie.

Comment: Yes, you understood my question perfectly! :) But I need a more spesific answer if that could be possible. I'm not sure how to do it! 
Thank youu! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving us much information here, but I'm assuming that `SmoothScroll` is the one from MooTools?
Take a look at this: http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-onload-smoothscroll

```
window.addEvent(‘domready’, function() {
    new SmoothScroll({ duration:700 }, window);
    var el = window.location.hash.substring(1); // the hash
    if(el) {
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
        var scroll = new Fx.Scroll(
            window,
            { wait: false, duration: 700, transition: Fx.Transitions.Quad.easeInOut }
        );
        scroll.toElement(el);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, its the one from moo tools! :) 
http://davidwalsh.name/smooth-scroll

Your code almost seems to work! :O But not quite.. It loads the page but does not scroll down to the anchor

Comment: exists something similar using jquery?